# version requested doesnt match

Tags: r, rselenium

I'm trying to use selenium package but I get an error.

```
chromever <- "113.0.5672.64" 
chromedriver <- ".../chromedriver.exe"
driver <- rsDriver(browser = "chrome", chromever = chromever, 
                   chromedriver = chromedriver)

checking Selenium Server versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking chromedriver versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
Error in chrome_ver(chromecheck[["platform"]], chromever) : 
  version requested doesnt match versions available = 112.0.5615.28,112.0.5615.49,113.0.5672.24,113.0.5672.63,114.0.5735.16
```

I download the version: 113.0.5672.24 and 113.0.5672.63, none works.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to go to directory "C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Local\binman\binman_chromedriver\win32" and create a new folder named as your Chrome version (since Chrome updates automatically as of today you should have 119.0.6045.105) than put the chromedriver.exe file into it.

Now your code should run. Recall to update your chrome version also in the rsDriver function call.